# Socket.io with multiple Node.js hosts, emit to all clients

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

I am new to Socket.io and trying to get my head around the best approach to solve this issue.

We have four instances of a Node.js app running behind a load balancer.

What I am trying to achieve is for another app to POST some data to the load balancer URL which will hand if off to one of the instances.

The receiving instance will store the data, then use Socket.io to emit the data to the connected clients.

The issue is that browser/client can only be connected to a single instance at one time.

I am trying to determine if there is a way to emit to all clients at once?

Or have the clients connect to multiple servers using io.connect?

Or is this a case for Redis?

Comment: It's a case for redis see http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publish/Subscribe is what you need here. Redis will give you the functionality your looking for out of the box. You just need to create a redis client and subscribe to an update channel on each of your app server nodes. Then, publish the update when a POST is successful (or whatever). Finally, have the redis client subscribe to the update chanel and on message emit a socketio event:

(truncated for brevity)

```
var express = require('express')  
  , socketio = require('socket.io')
  , redis = require('redis')
  , rc = redis.createClient()
;

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.post('/targets', function(req, res){
  rc.publish('update', res.body);
});

rc.on('connect', function(){
  // subscribe to the update channel
  rc.subscribe('update');
});

rc.on('message', function(channel, msg){
  // util.log('Channel: ' + channel + ' msg: ' + msg);
  var msg = JSON.parse(msg);
  io.sockets.in('update').emit('message', {
    channel: channel,
    msg: msg
  });
});
```

Then in the JS app, listen for that emitted message:

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
  debugger;
  // do something with the updated data  
});
```

Of course, introducing this new Redis Server adds another single point of failure. A more robust implementation may use something like a message broker with AMQP or ZeroMQ or some similar networking library which provides pub/sub capabilities.

Comment: We came to a similar conclusion as your last comment are will try this with Kafka. Very good answer though.